# "Venir" in the indefinite form after "il"?

Tags: grammaire, verbes

I ran across a phrase which confused me a little:

> J'entends quelqu'un **venir** du hall d'entrée.

How come that after *quelqu'un* goes the indefinite form of the verb *venir*?
I would expect it to be instead:

> J'entends quelqu'un **vient** du hall d'entrée.

Could you please explain this?

Comment: @None, Thanks, I mentioned it only because its presence might discourage others from posting a real answer (e.g. they feel they'd be plagiarizing or stealing it).  Yes I know that using comments to build an answer is okay, but even so it still has an effect.

Comment: By the way, a similar pattern is possible in English, although for most verbs the forms are so similar that you might not notice it. "I've never heard anyone be that rude before" (rather than "I've never heard anyone is that rude before"),  "I saw someone try to climb that tree yesterday", "We will never again see a human walk on the moon", etc.

Comment: @JamesMartin To a non native English speaker the comparison with English is not relevant since in the case of OP's sentence in English you could have either the V form or Ving form. (Only your 2nd sentence is of he same pattern as OP's sentence).

Answer (score 14):

In the sentence:

- *J'entends quelqu'un venir du hall d'entrée*.

*Quelqu'un* is the direct object of *entendre* and it is not the subject of *venir*. It means that *venir* has no subject. You could also write the sentence this way:

- *J'entends venir quelqu'un du hall d'entrée*.

The rule is that when a verb follows another verb then this second verb is in the infinitive<sup>1</sup>. In order to conjugate *venir* we need to give it a subject. We could write:

- *J'entends quelqu'un qui vient  du hall d'entrée*.

and then *qui* would be the subject and we would conjugate *venir*.

This does not mean that *quelqu'un* cannot be the subject of a verb. For example we could have this sentence:

- *Quelqu'un vient, je l'entends*.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Except when the 1st verb is *être* or *avoir*, but then they act as auxiliaries.</sup>

Comment: Another variant that would also work: *"J'entends **que** quelqu'un vient du hall d'entrée."*

Comment: @Bruno Transforming an independent clause into a subordinate clause doesn't make it a variant, *quelqu'un vient* is the subject of the verb in both cases. The question was **not** about sentence construction, in which case, yes, your sentence would have been a variant.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, English uses very similar grammar, with observed actions in the infinitive form:

> *I heard¹ someone **come** in from the hallway.*

and not in the indicative:

> ** *I heard someone **comes** in from the hallway.*
>
> ** *I heard someone **came** in from the hallway.*

Note that the sentences marked with ** above *are* technically also grammatical English, but they're examples of a different construction, essentially with an elided "that" after the verb "heard".

It's easy to tell them apart in this case because the implied meanings are different: in the first example above — just as in your French example sentence — you're saying you directly heard the noise someone made as they came in, while in the two examples marked with ** you're reporting *hearsay* about something someone reportedly does or did.

---

<sup>1) The English example works with both "hear" and "heard", i.e. both in present and past tense, but — at least to my ear — sounds more natural in the past tense.  I suspect this is because English also allows a similar construction using the present participle for the perceived action, as in "I hear/heard someone coming", and in most contexts the combination of a present tense verb for the act of observation (typically implying that you're still hearing them) with an infinitive for the observed action (implying that it has concluded) sounds less natural that the other alternatives.  It would be natural in a narrative that was entirely in the present tense, though, as in: "*I sit down to wait. Ten minutes later, I hear someone come in from the hallway.*"</sup>

Comment: This is a question about the [French Language](https://french.stackexchange.com/help) and not the place to explain English grammar.

Comment: @None: I tried to keep my explanation of English grammar to the minimum needed to illustrate the parallelism with French (and why it isn't perfect). That said, I could probably trim it down further yet.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal, in French sentence, if the first verb is conjugated, then, the second is not.

For exemple :

J'ai **entendu**  **courir**  au bout du couloir.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question that is asking why "after *quelqu'un* goes the indefinite form of the verb *venir?*"